# Which version of SproutCore should I use for a new project

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, sproutcore

I'm starting a project that is due to launch in about 4 months and I'll use SproutCore as the front end technology. 
There are two ways of installing described here http://wiki.sproutcore.com/Abbot-Setting+Up and I'd like to hear opinions about which version should be better for starting a new project. AFAIK, version 1.0 is starting to get dated but I don't know if I'll be able to handle bugs and lack of docs in the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bit late to respond, but version 1.4 will be coming out any day now (yes, 1.1 - 1.3 were skipped, long story). After that the quilmes branch on github will be on track for being version 1.5. If you want touch support you'll need quilmes/1.5 if you just want the latest and greatest without touch, you'll want master/1.4. If you have more questions, visit the IRC chat room at #sproutcore or check out the mailing list at sproutcore@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 0):

Use the install method where you get the latest from Git. Keep your application current.